# Angular Elements: contact all files into one bundle and contact their source maps

Tags: angular, source-maps, angular-elements

i'm trying to use Angular Elements for creating reusable component which will be  used old legacy project( which is java project without any front end libraries ) and i need to have one bundle for it instead of including separately scripts for zone.js, scripts.js and main.js.

But in dev mode i'm facing some problems with sourcemaps. Scripts.js and main.js have both sourcemaps and i'm really can't contact their sourcemaps correctly.

I've tried:

- simple concating with cat - sourcemaps do not work correctly. npm
- source-map-concat

Browser sees generated source map but can't handle it - i'm still debugging raw js.

For example this thing does not take in account sourcemaps :( https://www.telerik.com/blogs/getting-started-with-angular-elements

Any ideas how to do it properly?